# If $x\geq y$ and $a\geq b > 0$ then $xa \geq yb$? (Zdravko Cvetkovski, Inequalities: Theorems, Techniques and Selected Problems)

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, arithmetic

Let $x=y=-1$ and $a=2, b=1$. This seems to be counterexample to 4., in the following picture. Is the picture a mistake or am i confusing something?

[image: From Zdravko Cvetkovski, Inequalities: Theorems, Techniques and Selected Problems]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that there is a mistake. The corrected condition should be "$x,b \in \mathbb R^+$ or $a,y \in \mathbb R^+$".

If $x,b \in \mathbb R^+$, then $a \ge b \implies ax \ge bx$ and $x \ge y \implies bx \ge by$, so we conclude $ax \ge by$.

If $a,y \in \mathbb R^+$, then $x \ge y \implies ax \ge ay$ and $a \ge b \implies ay \ge by$, so we conclude $ax \ge by$.

Comment: My headcanon is that Zdravko Cvetkovski wrote the condition correctly, but because it looks so weird, an overly zealous editor "fixed" it.

Answer (score 0):

The correct statement can also be considered as follows:

If $x≥y$ and $a≥b$ then $xa≥yb$ for any $y,b\in\mathbb R^{+}$.

or

If $x≥y$ and $a≥b$ then $xa≥yb$, where $a,b\in\mathbb R{^+}$ and $x,y\in\mathbb R{^+}$.